# Convert a binary number in a list back to its decimal form in python?

Tags: python

How would I convert a binary string to a decimal number? I am taking the binary out of a list of values, and need to then convert it to decimal format.

ex. `x=["0b000101"]` needs to become `x= [5]`

Is this Possible?

Comment: is the "0b" in the string the substring that tells u that it's binary?

Answer (score 6):

```
In [66]: x
Out[66]: ['0b000101']

In [67]: [int(elt,base=2) for elt in x]
Out[67]: [5]
```